# Книги по Qt

Tags: qt, c++

Здравствуйте! Возник вопрос, существуют ли книги для изучения Qt, но не такие, как это обычно бывает, которые рассказывают что то конкретное и слишком обобщенно, а что то по-настоящему стоящее. Меня очень интересует именно весь Qt, начиная с его корневых составляющих, на чем все и как строится, модели, айтемы и прочие составляющие данной библиотеки. Желательно, что бы книги были на русском, но если на русском нет, не против прочитать и на английском.

Comment: qt сейчас активно развивается и впитывает в себя новые фичи (qml+ библиотеки qml типа qtdesktopcomponents, мобильные платформы), сомневаюсь что книги успевают за всем этим, особенно учитывая что 5.0 вышла менее 2-х месяцев назад. ПРо русский обычно и говорить не стоит - книги чаще всего выходятс опозданием на год, а то и два как правило

Comment: Ну допустим откинем русский. Но ведь есть же то, на чем Qt построен, откуда развивается, почему работает и прочее-прочее? Сомневаюсь, что с каждой новой версией библиотека переписывается с нуля, хотя, как я заметил, в 5.0 все очень сильно поменялось, но вряд ли поменялось ядро и принцип работы, а точнее философия Qt Именно это то меня и интересует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то я не очень понял Ваши "особенные" требования, но если будет полезен, вот список известных мне более-менее актуальных книжек на русском языке

- Макс Шлее "Qt4.8. Профессиональное
     программирование на С++"
- Боровский Андрей. "Qt4.7.
     Практическое программирование на С++"
- Бланшет, Саммерфильд. "Qt4.
     Программирование GUI на С++"